# Is there a better way to consume multiple Models than through ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm new working with ASP.NET MVC 2 and one of the examples I'm following [is the official ASP.NET MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com) on codeplex.

In the example project they have this scenario: There are three models: `Albums` , `Artists`, `Genres`.

What is making me doubt is the way they treat their views, for example, when they want to edit an album it's needed to have the list of all artists and genres from the database, so they make a ViewModel called `StoreManagerViewModel`:

```
public class StoreManagerViewModel{
  public Album Album{get;set;}
  public List<Artists> Artists{get;set;}
  public List<Genre> Genres{get;set;}
}
```

This ViewModel is passed to the view, and allows intellisense and to see multiple models in the view.

This method seems like it would make me  have a extra class for  almost every relation in my model:
If I have a a Discography class and I want to relate Artists to Discography, I would have to make another ViewModel like the above.

However, I don't like to have two properties inside the Album Method:

```
public List<Artists> Artists{get;set;}
public List<Genre> Genres{get;set;}
```

Is there a better way of doing this other than ViewModels? Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd have to make another view model to add discography information: couldn't you just add a `Discography` property to `Artist` or add a dictionary of discographies to the existing view model?

Comment: It's just because when editing an album, you need to pass the list of ALL albums to the view (of course in the Album class you have a property with the current discography and artitst of that album)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the other answers on this page so far have left out one important concept of a view model, that it separates the data layer from the presentation layer, and removes the ability for the view to construct queries which could crush your db.  Its not just about intellisense and sending multiple models to the view, although those are other pluses.

Say for instance you want to load up on your site the top 100 stack overflow users whose name starts with `myNamePrefix`.  Then for each user you want to display a list of the tags in for which they have more than 10 upvotes for.  You *could* just pass a list of `Users` to your view, and then call the `.Tags` property, which would then make a round trip to the db for each of your 100 users.  This might be fine when the db resides on the same machine as the web server and you're only getting a few hits per day.  But lets say you you're trying to serve up this data for various values of `myNamePrefix` every second.  You could probably find some creative ways to cache results, but for the most part, its better to populate your view model with all the data it needs (in this case via a single query), and just have the view spit out the results.  Remember, its the view's job to display the data, not to fetch it.

Comment: I agree with you and that's why I'm trying to keep the views as strongly tipped and avoid inserting to model classes parameters or properties that actually are for a particular view, not part of the model or business logic. I guess the trick is to separate those ViewModels from the "real" models (creating a folder for example) in order to avoid mixing both concepts

Comment: I almost always implement my "real" models, or whatever ORM system I'm using, in a separate project, even if it's just dragging/dropping tables from the server explorer to a dbml.  Its not necessary, but it draws a finite line of where the data stops and the web app begins.  The web app itself is just a view for whatever the "real" model is anyway.  The MVC app's models folder is then filled with view models only.

Answer (score 1):

The reason they choose to create a separate `ViewModel` instead of using a Model already created such as `Albums`, `Artist`, or `Genre` is because all 3 were required.  If only one was required such as `Albums` it would have been fine to transfer just `Album` or `IList<Album>` depending on the use.

In ASP.NET MVC the Model can be any object in the system that you want to send to the View.  Even `string`, `int`, and any other base type.

In ASP.NET MVC 3 you can also use the `dynamic` keyword as your ViewModel, so that you don't even have to specify the type.  However you should probably avoid this until it is a last resort, because it is always better to have a statically typed ViewModel.

Lastly, you don't have to specify a Model at all, you can set and pull information from the ViewModel dictionary.  But this probably should be avoided for anything more complex than the most simple information, because just like `dynamic` it isn't statically typed.

Comment: I think in general is a good practice to keep things strongly tipped, it creates less spaghetti code (apart from the Intellisense, which is actually a great help). So, the only propose of this ViewModels is to pass related data to the view , isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel is there for two reasons:

1. Intellisense support.
2. Instances where passing a simple model simply isn't enough for your view.

The ViewModel allows you to send multiple Models to your view in cases where it makes sense -- there are a lot of cases where one simple Model just doesn't do.

There are also cases where you only need to send one View to your model.  Use it where it makes sense, and when you only need to send one Model to a view (and you don't care about intellisense) then only send one model to that view.

Answer (score 0):

when you're using Linq to SQL, every model will have its children and parent loaded in the object (when your DB is good). So in that case the original model is very often all you need in an edit view or a create view. because your model will be made for you.

`ViewModels` IS the clean way.

the dirty way is using `ViewData`. well, 'dirty'. if you need a `SelectList` together with your model, using `ViewData` is not dirty, it's the best way in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. You could use ChildActions.

Child actions can be cached and each child action can be called from multiple views.

Using child actions can be a better solution if you have ViewModels that overlap. For example, if every view has a sidebar, you can render it using childaction, and since it's cached, db wouldn't be queried for sidebar's model.

This is just another way. Wich one is better depends on problem you're trying to solve.